# DataGridView: Bailing out of cell validation

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I'm handling CellValidating and setting `e.Cancel = true` if the data in the cell is invalid. This almost gets me where I want to be, but the problem is if the user has some invalid data in the cell, the rest of the UI is essentially off-limits until they fix the error or press Esc.

Since pressing Esc might not be intuitive to certain users, they may find it frustrating that they can't e.g. click on the "Back" button I have on the form to leave the screen altogether. (In such a scenario, their change-in-progress should be discarded as if they had pressed Esc.)

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I do like that they aren't allowed to start editing other cells without fixing errors in their current cell, but I'd prefer they still be able to press the "Back"/"Cancel" buttons on the form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be possible to set the `CausesValidation` property to false, or is your validation cancellation cell specific? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx

Comment: @keyboardP That seemed to at least partially work, as now the Cancel button can be used with invalid data in a cell. Convert your comment to an answer and I will upvote you. (Not sure why Back doesn't work yet.)

Comment: Are the Back and Cancel buttons within the same parent control?

Comment: @keyboardP Yes. It's possible it's because the Back button does something that does cause validation regardless, whereas the Cancel button basically prompts to close the form.

Comment: Try just having the Back button just display a MessageBox to see if it works when it's not related to the DGV. Or, you could enable the `CausesValidation` property when the back button is pressed (MouseDown?). At least at this point, the user shouldn't be stuck within a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation.aspx) property to `false`.